# Is there a way to download Microsoft Teams conversation history to text file or excel?

Tags: data-analysis, microsoft-teams

I am trying to download Microsoft teams conversation history for analytics purpose but couldnt find straight forward way to do it.

Is there any API available from Microsoft on this.

Comment: Please take a look at [Get Channel Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) graph API to fetch channel messages

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know is to use the MS Graph App to what you want to do. You need to be an admin in Teams you need an Azure account to set the app. Best to have admin rights too.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 you have [the export page](https://privacy.teams.live.com/ui/en/dataexport) that you can access